# Adjusting mdadm priority on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, software-raid, raid-1, mdadm

I have Ubuntu 12.04 running on my new server, and it is setup to run off of one drive, then 2 drives that are mirrored using `mdadm`. When streaming files or media from it, it is extremely slow. I was told that by default, `mdadm` uses 10% of my CPU for the array. So what I would like to know is, **how can I increase the read speed of an array?** I don't see options in `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`, and Googling doesn't reveal anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in these two files:

- `/proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min`
- `/proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_max`

These two files contain the minimum and maximum values of speed in kB/s.

Do something like this and maybe the repair speed will increase:

```
echo 200000 >  /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min
echo 500000 >  /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_max
```

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mdadm#Increasing_RAID_ReSync_Performance

Notes:

- The `/proc/mdstat` file tells you about the current speed process
- I know nothing about the -G option in the Wikipedia article
- This actually did not help increasing the repair process speed on my own RAID array. It was stuck at around 130000K/sec.